# How to get the Identity value from C# object initializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I  am using Object initializer to insert data into table using Entity Framework. Data is saving into database perfectly , but i want to retrieve the Identity  from that table .

Here is my code :-

```
db.CMSQUEs.Add(new CMSQUE
  {
    queedfcodequestiontype = questionEdfValue.ToString(),
    quenotes = model.QuestionDescription,
    queisexternaltext = false,
    quenumofoptions = model.NoofOptions,
    queusmrefidcreatedby = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["usmrefid"]),
    quescore = model.QuestionScore / model.NoofQuestions,
    quetime = model.QuestionDuration  
  });

 db.SaveChanges();
```

But I don't know how to retrieve the Identity  from that table ??

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-retrieve-Id-of-inserted-entity-using-Entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first keep the entity object then reload it after you have inserted it:

```
var cmsque = new CMSQUE
{
    queedfcodequestiontype = questionEdfValue.ToString(),
    quenotes = model.QuestionDescription,
    queisexternaltext = false,
    quenumofoptions = model.NoofOptions,
    queusmrefidcreatedby = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["usmrefid"]),
    quescore = model.QuestionScore / model.NoofQuestions,
    quetime = model.QuestionDuration  
};

db.CMSQUEs.Add(cmsque);
db.SaveChanges();
db.Entry(cmsque).GetDatabaseValues();

var identityValue = cmsque.ID;
```

Comment: I don't have the minimum point to upvote you. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
var cmsQueue = new CMSQUEUE { ... };
db.CMSQUEs.Add(cmsQueue);
db.SaveChanges();

// Get the id from the object.
var id = cmsQueue.Id;
```

Entity Framework makes sure the identity property is set on the object you insert. So it's simply a matter of rearranging some code.